# Yahoo Fantasy Sports API Timestamp Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, yahoo

I am trying replicate this PHP script in Nodejs that can be found here. I am using the "Full OAuth Flow without Libraries" script

https://developer.yahoo.com/fantasysports/guide/GettingStarted.html

I am able to get my request token and use it to get the access token without any problems. However, when I make the actual call to the API with my Nodejs script, I get an error code 401 with message "Unauthorized". When I run the PHP script I get following XML from the returned contents

Return code: 401
Contents:

```
<yahoo:error xmlns:yahoo='http://yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng'
xml:lang='en-US'>
<yahoo:description>Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem="timestamp_refused", realm="yahooapis.com"</yahoo:description>
</yahoo:error>
```

I am assuming my own Nodejs script is having the same problem with the timestamp but I have no way to prove it.

Here is my Nodejs code:

```
var accessToken = accessTokenData["oauth_token"];
var accessTokenSecret = accessTokenData["oauth_token_secret"];

// 4. Make request using access token
var protocol = "https:"
var baseUrl = "fantasysports.yahooapis.com";
var requestUri = "/fantasy/v2/game/nfl";
var requestUrl = protocol + "//" + baseUrl + requestUri;

console.log("Making request for " + requestUrl + " ...\n");

makeRequest(
consumerKey,
consumerSecret,
accessToken,
accessTokenSecret,
protocol,
baseUrl,
requestUri
)

//In makeSignedRequest
paramString += "&oauth_signature=" + encodeURIComponent(signature);
var finalPath = path + "?" + paramString

 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var data = {
           "error_str": "",
           "errno": 0,
           "return_code": 0,
           "contents": ""
        }

        var options = {
            "protocol": protocol,
            "host": host,
            "path": finalPath,
            "timeout": 2
        };

        console.log("options: " + JSON.stringify(options, null, 2));

        https.get(options, (res) => {
    //....
```

Has anyone else used this basic starter script? The timestamp is absolute because it is based on Greenwich time from New Years 1970.

**UPDATE:**

My server's clock was wrong. I updated the the clock and now I am getting the following error when I run the PHP script:

Return code: 500
Contents:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<yahoo:error xmlns:yahoo='http://yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng'
  xml:lang='en-US'>
  <yahoo:description>Internal server error</yahoo:description>
</yahoo:error>
```

I am also getting this error when I run the script locally on my laptop. Perhaps the services are down temporarily?

However, I am still getting a 401 Unauthorized error in my Nodejs which means there is something different between the scripts. Once I can get this PHP script to return a valid payload, I will begin fixing my Node to match it.

Comment: What timestamp are you using? Note that php `time()` produces seconds not ms the way javascript Date.getTime() does. Would try using an oauth2 library instead of rolling your own

Comment: ill note that but that was the code Yahoo provided, so I assumed it would work. Do you have a feel for the normal type of timestamp that is used in oauth2?

Comment: I wrote a php back end for Yhoo fantasy using Oath2 based on the flow in their guide. I don't see anywhere in my code I send any timestamp for it. I only use it for a personal app that has an angular front end. I also hated their json structure and ended up writing my own xml->json parser. Their xml has a much cleaner structure

Comment: Also their is a node yhoo fantasy library that might help you  https://github.com/whatadewitt/yfsapi. I used it a bit myself (before they implemented Oauth2) but wanted a separate back end I could keep alive using oauth2 and also use  more reasonable json structure